# Checking to see if Cursor is in rectangle bounds

Tags: vb.net, drawing

I have a program that randomly sets the cursor that an x,y coordinate and then clicks. I have this function/sub that creates a rectangle based on certain parameters.

```
Private Sub drawTitleBarRectangle()

    Dim titleBarRectangle As Rectangle = RectangleToScreen(Me.ClientRectangle)
    Dim titleBarRectangleHeight As Integer = titleBarRectangle.Top - Me.Top
    Dim titleBarRectangleWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
    Dim titleBarRectangleTop As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Top

    Dim titleBarBounds As New Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, titleBarRectangleWidth, titleBarRectangleHeight)
End Sub
```

I want to check if when the cursor is at it's x,y position if it is within the bounds of the rectangle created from that function or not. Right now I have this:

```
       drawTitleBarRectangle()
            SetCursorPos(x, y)
            If titleBarRectangle.Contains(x, y) Then
                leftClick(800, 800)
            End If
```

The `Private titleBarRectangle` is from a global variable that I declare as `Private titleBarRectangle As New Drawing.Rectangle` I'm not too sure why it's there to be honest...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the variables in the initial method you've listed are **local** variables.  This means they are simply discarded when that method exits.  You need to update the class level variable you've declared by making an assignment instead of a declaration.  With that in mind, it should look more like:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private titleBarRectangle As Rectangle

    Private Sub drawTitleBarRectangle()
        Dim rc As Rectangle = Me.RectangleToScreen(Me.ClientRectangle)
        Dim titleBarRectangleHeight As Integer = rc.Top - Me.Top
        titleBarRectangle = New Rectangle(Me.Location.X, Me.Location.Y, Me.Width, titleBarRectangleHeight)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        drawTitleBarRectangle()
        Debug.Print(titleBarRectangle.ToString)
        ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(titleBarRectangle, Color.Black, FrameStyle.Dashed)

        Dim x As Integer = titleBarRectangle.Location.X + titleBarRectangle.Width / 2
        Dim y As Integer = titleBarRectangle.Location.Y + titleBarRectangle.Height / 2
        Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y)
        If titleBarRectangle.Contains(Cursor.Position) Then
            Debug.Print("It's in there!")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Notice how the last line in the method will use the class level variable instead of a local since we don't have `Dim` in front of it.

Comment: Ok, so then to check if the cursor is inside the bounds or not would I still use: `drawTitleBarRectangle()
                SetCursorPos(x, y)
                If titleBarRectangle.Contains(x, y) Then
                    leftClick(800, 800)
                End If`

Comment: Sure, that'll work fine...assuming `x` and `y` are proper values in **screen** coords.  By the way, you don't need the SetCursorPos() API as you can simply do `Cursor.Position = New Point(x, y)`.

Comment: Ok, so last question. When I run the program now the bounds of `titleBarRectangle` is just (0,0,0,0)... :/